# C# Insert value into DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem with a `DataGridView`, as you can see from down here, when I enter a value (*LOL*) within the cells is actually only it appears in the last line

[image: DataGridView]

**Code:**

```
private void CaricaNoteLavaggio()
{
    using (DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection())
    {
        const string query = "" // My query
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(query))
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                    dataGridNoteLavaggio.Rows.Add(row);

                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridNoteLavaggio.Rows[dataGridNoteLavaggio.NewRowIndex].Cells)
                    {
                        cell.Value = "LOL";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The columns of the `DataGridView` I create dynamically using this piece of code (if that can be useful)

```
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtId = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        txtId.HeaderText = "ID";
        txtId.Name = "id";
        txtId.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        txtId.Visible = false;

        dataGridNoteLavaggio.Columns.Add(txtId);

        // Function that returns the list of languages (EN, FR, ES, etc. ...)
        List<string> lingue = DatabaseFunctions.GetLingue();
        foreach (var lingua in lingue)
        {
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtDesc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            txtDesc.HeaderText = lingua;
            txtDesc.Name = lingua;
            txtDesc.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;

            dataGridNoteLavaggio.Columns.Add(txtDesc);
        }
```

I tried it with debugging to follow the indices in the cycle are correct but despite the result is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you insert data in the new row and new row always added to last of all.

for change data from first row after adding row you must change this code:

```
dataGridNoteLavaggio.Rows[dataGridNoteLavaggio.NewRowIndex].Cells
```

to

```
dataGridNoteLavaggio.Rows[index].Cells
```

and `index` set from `Rows.Add()` method. and your codes should like this:

```
private void CaricaNoteLavaggio()
{
    using (DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection())
    {
        const string query = "" // My query
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(query))
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                    var index = dataGridNoteLavaggio.Rows.Add(row);

                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridNoteLavaggio.Rows[index].Cells)
                    {
                        cell.Value = "LOL";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```